# How to remove more than 2 consecutive NA's in a column?

Tags: r, datetime, duplicates, missing-data

I am new to R, In my data Frame I have col1("Timestamp"), col2("Values"). I have to remove rows of more than 2 consecutive NA in col2. My dataframe Looks like the below one,

```
Timestamp  | values  
-----------|--------
2011-01-02 |  2  
2011-01-03 |  3  
2011-01-04 |  NA  
2011-01-05 |  1  
2011-01-06 |  NA  
2011-01-07 |  NA    
2011-01-08 |  8  
2011-01-09 |  6  
2011-01-10 |  NA  
2011-01-11 |  NA  
2011-01-12 |  NA  
2011-01-13 |  2
```

I would like to remove more than 2 duplicate rows based on second column. Expected output -

```
Timestamp  | values  
-----------|--------
2011-01-02 |  2  
2011-01-03 |  3  
2011-01-04 |  NA  
2011-01-05 |  1  
2011-01-06 |  NA  
2011-01-07 |  NA    
2011-01-08 |  8  
2011-01-09 |  6 
2011-01-13 |  2
```

I'm looking for the solution thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the dates matter? (do they have to be consecutive?)

Comment: yeah they are consecutive but deleting Date is not a problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the run length encoding function `rle`. I assume that the data is already sorted by date.

```
r <- rle(is.na(df$values))                      # check runs of NA in value column
df[!rep(r$values & r$lengths > 2, r$lengths),]  # remove runs of >2 length
```

Comment: Thank you so much it made my Job simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `rleid` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by the run-length-id of 'values', we get the row index (`.I`) where the number of rows is greater than 2 (`.N >2`) and (`&`) `all` the 'values' are 'NA'.  Extract the index (`$V1`) to subset the rows of original dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[!(.N >2 & all(is.na(values)))], rleid(is.na(values))]$V1]
#    Timestamp values
#1: 2011-01-02      2
#2: 2011-01-03      3
#3: 2011-01-04     NA
#4: 2011-01-05      1
#5: 2011-01-06     NA
#6: 2011-01-07     NA
#7: 2011-01-08      8
#8: 2011-01-09      6
#9: 2011-01-13      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this one liner code:

```
Df[!duplicated(Df$column),]
```

Comment: ohh you want to remove if it is more than two! ok!